# Relative path in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i searched for this but found nothing relevant to me.

in VB.NET , i have a String var called PDF_Path .
i want to insert into PDF_Path the path of the GuideLine.PDF file that i have in the visual studio project .

my project tree in visual studio :

```
 Solution 'XML Slave'(1 project)
 XML SLAVE
    |______(FOLDER)docs
           |______**GuideLine.PDF** 
    |______(FOLDER)Images
    |______(FOLDER)Resources
    |______about.vb
    |______MainForm.vb
    |______MsgForm.vb
```

the GuideLine.PDF file is in "docs" folder .
how i can get the path of the file in visual studio and insert the path into String PDF_Path variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [My](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffec36z.aspx) namespace to access quick and handy features, like [DirectoryPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/6whasz3x(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Dim PDF_Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "\docs\GuideLine.PDF")
```

Also remember to set the Copy To Output Directory property to Copy always, just to be sure that the file will be available in the executing working folder of the app.

**TIP:** Do not put underscore chars in your variable identifiers, just use the globally accepted lower *camelCase* style for local vars.

```
Dim pdfPath
```

Comment: Hey matteo , its not working .. i set :  pdfPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\docs\GuideLine.PDF") , and tried to print the path to see if its working but its not , its showing me :C:\Users\gedaan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XML Slave\XML Slave\bin\Debug\docs\GuideLine.PDF ..... i dont have a folder in debug called docs.

Comment: @Gedaan : Your application is always located in `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`. You cannot reference a directory that's part of the project since that won't be available once the application is released. You have to put the `docs` folder in `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` in instead.

Comment: @Gedaan if you are debugging you will need to create that folder and place a copy of the file in there for testing. Once you deploy you will again need to ensure the file is deployed with the application so the path works. It's why we have `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` to make things like this easier and to save "hardcoding" paths which will eventually fail. On another note, good answer Matteo.

Comment: @Gedaan : Just set the target file properties as following: BuildAction=Content and Copy To Output Directory=Always. That should work without any manual copy